# What does a "null" result mean in the Census ACS API?

Tags: api, us-census

There are ACS 5 variables that are available at the tract level, but return `null` at the block group level. For example, median monthly housing costs:

http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acs5/?get=B25105_001E&for=tract:*&in=state:17%20county:001

http://api.census.gov/data/2014/acs5/?get=B25105_001E&for=block%20group:*&in=state:17%20county:001%20tract:00100

What does a `null` value signify? Is it that the variable is never available at the block group level, or just for some/most of the block groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A null result means that the [variable has been suppressed for that geography](http://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/data-suppression.html). [Some variables are always suppressed for a certain level of geometry](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/tech_docs/data_suppression/geographic_restrictions.xlsx), but even if a variable is usually available for a level of geometry, it may still be suppressed for a particular geometry because of:

- Population Thresholds
- Data Quality Filtering
- Disclosure Review Board Rules

Answer (score 5):

Table B25105 is [not available](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/summary_file/2014/documentation/tech_docs/ACS_2014_SF_5YR_Appendices.xls) at the Block Group level. The appendices show which tables are available at the block group level.

Comment: That's a useful link, but doesn't quite answer my question. Is there any other reason, besides block group exclusion for a variable to be null?

Comment: You are requesting an estimate at the block group level from Table B25105, but the Census Bureau does not publish that table at that geographic summary level. I guess they choose to return a null value in the API.

Comment: I think that's right in this case, but I'm asking about null in general.